# temporary storage in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a web app where a user enters some text into a textarea and then goes to another page where that text needs to be available.  The text might be too long to pass as a GET query parameter, but it is only used once when the user clicks through to the next page.  How should I temporarily store this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache expiration is unpredictable. Treat it as a short-lived cache.

More reliable options includes cookies (either stash the data temporarily in a cookie, or have the cookie hold a datastore key to where you've saved the data), or embed the temporary data in a hidden field in a form on the subsequent page.

Comment: All the answers are informative, but the cookie with a datastore key makes the most sense to me for my situation, so I'm choosing this answer as "best".

Answer (score 3):

You can store in [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview) up to 1 megabyte of any information.

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
# store user info in memcache
# using USER_ID var if form can be submitted by different users
memcache.set('%s_text' % USER_ID, DATA)

# get info and clear memory
DATA = memcache.get('%s_text' % USER_ID)
memcache.delete('%s_text' % USER_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It does talk about memcache's expiration being unpredictable.  Should I worry about this in my case?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a cookie. Not sure how much exactly you can store in a cookie but it should be enough for your purposes.

Comment: I googled cookie size limits and browsers seem to impose a 4KB limit

Answer (score 1):

We put out an open-source library that implements the memcache interface (well most of it), but backed by Datastore, so that you don't have to worry about evictions.

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-dscache/

j